# Turning off Points of Interest Labels Bing Map AJAX v7.0

Tags: ajax, bing-maps

I am wondering if there is a way to turn off the labels that appear on the Bing Map labeling things like public beaches or popular businesses?  I believe in Google Maps they are called Points of Interest and are simple enough to disable.  And I also know I could turn the Labels off completely by disabling that layer using something like this:

```
map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key', labelOverlay: Microsoft.Maps.LabelOverlay.hidden});
```

But I want things like street labels so just wondering if I can just select these "Points of Interest" to disable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this tagged "google-maps"?

Comment: Was thinking that maybe people with experience with Google maps might be able to relate it to Bing Maps.  My apologies I can remove the tag.

Answer (score 1):

The LabelOverlay option is for the map labels in the Aerial imagery. When this is set to hidden and the map is in aerial or birdseye mode you will see the imagery without the labels displayed on the map. There is no option to turn of the point of interest labels as they are drawn right on the map tiles themselves and are not a separate layer of data.